# Redireccionar despues de Loguearse en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, rutas

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en laravel, version 6.5.2.
Usé los siguientes comandos para generar la autenticación:

```
composer require laravel/ui "^1.2" 
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Funciona.
Me registro y me manda a la pagina que le he dicho en el RegisterController.php, tan sólo cambié

```
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
```

y funciona, pero cuando tan sólo estoy iniciando sesión, la página se queda cargando y no llega a nada.
En este caso también cambié esa misma variable en el LoginController.php y no sé por qué pasa eso.
Pero si hago click en ¨Laravel¨  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entra a la página a la que intento redireccionar, lo que quiere decir que sí se está creando el token de sesión.

Agradecería alguna respuesta.

Comment: Osea se queda en blanco cuando le das a Login o a Laravel?. El cambio de esas variables no tendría por que afectar eso que se queda en blanco te daría en su caso un 404 de que no encuentra esa ruta, puede ser eso, sino tienes una página que muestre el 404 de que la ruta a la que intentas hacer la re-dirección no existe.

Comment: Debes editar la constante ubicada en `RouteServiceProvider`? Además también tienes la opción de sobrescribir el método `authenticated()` en tu `LoginController`. Revisar aquí la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#included-authenticating